# Trying to understand IEEE double precision format

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I am currently studying Numerical Analysis and it has introduced the IEEE double precision standard.

sign: 1 bit

exponent: 11 bits (nmin = -1022, nmax = 1023)

mantissa: 53(with an implicit leading bit, so only 52 are stored)

What I am confused about is how we interpret the numbers from this format.

For normal numbers, is the implicit leading 1 part of the integer or is it part of the fraction?

From what I have searched so far, I think the leading 1 is in the integer part. However, the textbook I use mentions Decimal Machine Number and it uses the representation`0.d1d2....x 10^n`, which makes me wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: Why not write a program? Take number you already know (say, 1/2) and see what the result is.

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous, because you can switch from one format (1 bit before the point, 52 bits after) to the other (53 bits after the point, none before) and back without affecting the set of values represented simply by adjusting the exponent by +/-1. The IEEE 754 standard uses the first format in its descriptions (see IEEE 754-2008 section 3.4); the C standard uses the second. (See e.g. C99 5.2.4.2.2p2.)

Comment: ... So the answer depends on what other information you've been given: i.e., about what to do with the exponent and significand once you have them. If (as seems likely) you're using the formulas from the IEEE 754-2008 document, then yes, the implicit leading 1 bit is the first bit *before* the point; i.e., part of the integer.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I see. Thanks for the clarification. I didn't realize I could check the C standard .